# LogicApp error occurs whenever I try to push data to CRM

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

Everything appears correct within my Logic App:

Extracting data from CosmosDB, Pushing to CRM and then returning this data to CosmosDB.
However, I keep getting this error 400.

Here is my code:

**Extracting and parsing data from CosmosDB**
[image]

[image]

**Pushing data that I have in CosmosDB that I wish to go into CRM**

[image]

**Returning data with newly replaced CRMid back into the original CosmosDB container**
[image]

[image]

**However I keep getting this error:**

```
  Body:
   {
        "_ems_leadpm_value": "test
        "_ems_leadpmforfeature_value": "",
        "_ems_productname_value": "",
        "_ownerid_value": "test",
        "ems_featurdescription": "test.",
        "ems_featurename": "test
        "ems_keywords": ""
  }
```

**Specific error: 400, what does position 8 mean? it seems the program is wanting me to add parentheses or a comma? but where should this be added? I am still trying to research this and am unsure.**

```
    {
       "status": 400,
       "message": "')' or ',' expected at position 8 in '(test)'.",
       "error": {
       "message": "')' or ',' expected at position 8 in '(test)'."
     },
       "source": "test.crm.dynamics.com",
       "errors": [],
       "debugInfo": "clientRequestId: 1111111"
   }
```

**Any suggestion or advice is appreciated**

Comment: The JSON payload in your `Body: { ... }` in invalid

Comment: Ok I will research this. Is the JSON payload something that I created? Where would it originate from?, How would I clear this error?

Comment: I assume it's in the body of the HTTP request that is triggering the flow

Comment: Ok thank you I will check. It is strange though because this part executes correctly, its only when I try to push the data to CRM do I see this error